# Macro for putting a separator between inline list items

Tags: macros

It's late, so I may not be thinking about this clearly enough, but I could have sworn that there exists a macro (possibly not part of a package, but just something that I picked up somewhere along the way) that is able to take some sort of inline list separated by a certain character and replace that character with another string.  For example, something like

```
\ThisImaginaryMacro{apples;oranges;peaches;pears}
```

would produce something like

```
apples $\cdot$ oranges $\cdot$ peaches $\cdot$ pears
```

because somewhere I've specified that semicolons should be replaced with `$\cdot$`.

I have been searching through all the `.tex` files I've made in recent memory, and I just can't seem to find this, and it's driving me nuts, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in many ways. For instance with `xstring`:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\RealMacro}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{;}{$\cdot$}}
```

However this requires you to be very strict in inputting the argument without spaces around the semicolons.

A quite robust solution uses `xparse` and the LaTeX3 packages:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\RealMacro}{ O{~$\cdots$~} m }
 {
  \ryan_change_semicolons:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

 \seq_new:N \l_ryan_input_seq

 \cs_new_protected:Npn \ryan_change_semicolons:nn #1 #2
  {
   \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ryan_input_seq { ; } { #2 }
   \seq_use:Nnnn \l_ryan_input_seq { #1 } { #1 } { #1 }
  }
 \ExplSyntaxOff
```

With this definition you don't have to worry if you input either one of

```
\RealMacro{apples;oranges;peaches;pears}
\RealMacro{apples ; oranges; peaches;pears}
```

because leading and trailing spaces will be removed. The macro allows also for a call such as

```
\RealMacro[, ]{apples;oranges;peaches;pears}
```

and the output would be

> apples, oranges, peaches, pears

The default value of the optional argument is `<space>$\cdot$<space>` as requested.

Answer (score 3):

Just to offer an alternative to looping over the list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup\lccode`\~`\;\lowercase{\endgroup
\def\ThisImaginaryMacro#1{\gdef~{\cdot}$\mathcode`\;"8000 \mathrm{#1}$}}
\begin{document}

\ThisImaginaryMacro{apples;oranges;peaches;pears}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of task is conveniently done by a recursive macro:

```
%recursive ``low-level'' macro
\def\sToC#1;#2\nil{#1\ifx\empty#2\empty\else\space$\cdot$\space\sToC#2\nil\fi}

%user-friendly ``driver'' macro
\def\semicToCdot#1{\expandafter\sToC#1;\nil}

\semicToCdot{apples;oranges;peaches;pears}

\bye
```